# Shell script to copy and prepend folder name to files from multiple subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rename, batch-rename

I have several folders with different images sharing file names, with a folder structure like this:

```
/parent/folder001/img001.jpg
/parent/folder001/img002.jpg
/parent/folder002/img001.jpg
/parent/folder002/img002.jpg
/parent/folder003/img001.jpg
/parent/folder003/img002.jpg
...
```

and would like to copy/rename these files into a new folder, like this:

```
/newfolder/folder001_img001.jpg
/newfolder/folder001_img002.jpg
/newfolder/folder002_img001.jpg
/newfolder/folder002_img002.jpg
/newfolder/folder003_img001.jpg
/newfolder/folder003_img002.jpg
...
```

(It's probably better if newfolder isn't a subfolder of parent, since that might end up causing really weird recursion.)

None of the folders containing images have any subfolders.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to reuse the script to "update" newfolder, since I might need to add more folders-containing-images later along the line.

How can I accomplish this with a shell script?

Comment: Well, renaming them all manually isn't really an option, there's hundreds. I'm afraid I'm not terribly adept at the shell myself yet, but looking for solutions only turned up results for different problems/directory structures entirely.

Comment: Does it take as input the source folder (in this case "/parent/"), and destination folder (in this case "/newfolder") then grab all the folders within the source folder to merge into the destination folder?

Comment: While renaming the files in the folders within the source folder accordingly, yeah. That would be very helpful! Though I suppose it might be enough if the script works from inside the parent folder and merges the image folders in a folder that's in the same directory as the parent folder is?

Comment: I see.  So no input into the script.  Source and destination dir are the current directory.  And you can rerun it to update.  Also, do updates cause deletions of files no longer in a sub-directory?

Comment: Aah, no, that's not really necessary. Just it copy-renaming over the files currently present in the image folders would be enough. (Since all it'd take for that, should it ever become necessary, is to delete all files in the destination folder before executing the script and stuff.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit tedious but will do:

```
#!/bin/bash
parent=/parent
newfolder=/newfolder
mkdir "$newfolder"
for folder in "$parent"/*; do
  if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
    foldername="${folder##*/}"
    for file in "$parent"/"$foldername"/*; do
      filename="${file##*/}"
      newfilename="$foldername"_"$filename"
      cp "$file" "$newfolder"/"$newfilename"
    done
  fi
done
```

Put the **parent** path to `parent` variable and **newfolder** path to `newfolder` variable.

Comment: Don't store the glob results in scalar variables, that removes the white space safety. Just use them directly - `for folder in /parent/*`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, while it creates the new folder just fine, it's not copying over the files yet. The output gives something like the following: `cp: omitting directory ‘/parent/folder001’` for each folder in parent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Kevin,
@ Nekkowe, try again with this edited code.

Comment: @Jahid I'm a bit confused about this one. Which bits do I replace with the path of the parent folder? When I tried replacing every instance of /parent/ with the correct path, `$ ./photorename-2.sh
bash: ./photorename-2.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` happened.

Comment: only `/parent` in 2 places

Comment: edited, you can put the parent path to `parent` variable. Don't use `/` at end.

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like this:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; fnew=$(rev <<< "$f" | sed 's~/~_~' | rev); echo "mv $f $fnew"' \;
```

This looks for files within the current directory structure and perform the following:

- get the file name
- replace the last `/` with `_`.
- write `echo "cp $old_file $new_file"`

Once you have run this and seen it prints the proper command, remove the `echo` so that it effectively does the `mv` command.

I know the `fnew=$(rev <<< "$f" | sed 's~/~_~' | rev)` is a bit ugly trick, but I couldn't find a better way to replace the last `/` with `_`. Maybe `sed -r 's~/([^/]*)$~_\1~'` could also be appropiate, but I always like using `rev` :)

---

Since your `find` does not behave well with the `-sh c` expression, let's use a `while` loop for it:

```
while read -r file
do
    new_file=$(rev <<< "$file" | sed 's~/~_~' | rev)
    echo "mv $file $new_file"; done < <(find . -type f)
done < <(find . -type f)
```

As a one-liner:

```
while read -r file; do new_file=$(rev <<< "$file" | sed 's~/~_~' | rev); echo "mv $file $new_file"; done < <(find . -type f)
```

Comment: Oh, uh, the only output it seems to give so far is: `sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected` ...repeated over a lot of lines (it does terminate at some point). I tried executing it both in parent and in a subfolder, with identical results.

Comment: What machine are you using? This works fine for `find GNU 4.5.11`. Does this even work to you? --> `find -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; echo "$f"' \;`.

Comment: That one outputs a lot of rows with a single '$' in each.

Comment: If the script is supposed to output the respective file names, it's not working as intended. Presumably I'm either using it wrong (I tried executing it from the terminal, inside each an image and the parent folder), or missing something else?

Comment: @Nekkowe my guess is that your `find` version does not support this, which is a pity. Maybe we should approach this through a `while` loop getting `find` as input. Will see if I can get some time to write it down.

Comment: Aah. Thank you for your time! If it helps, I've uploaded the output of 'find --help' on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/WDHVk5mY

Comment: @Nekkowe I see. I just updated with the `while` approach, take a look at it, maybe it solves your issue.

Comment: Try: `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'f=$0; echo "$f"' {} \;`

Comment: @WilliamPursell does `f=$0` behave like `f={}`?

Comment: @fedorqui It works like a charm, kinda sorta. While it does rename the files correctly (I took the liberty of replacing mv with cp for now, though), it copies all files into /parent, and executing the script a second time basically doubles the file count by renaming the files already in parent from e.g. `folder001_img001.jpg` to `._folder001_img001.jpg`. So that's a bit of a problem still >~< Is there a way to define a path for a target directory to put the copy/renamed files into?

Comment: @Nekkowe the `.` comes from `find .`, so you can for example say `find /your/path`. Use `echo` again to see how the output looks like, but it should be fine with my current solution.

Comment: f=$0 assigns the zeroth positional parameter of the shell to f, and passing {} as the argument to sh makes the filename the zeroth argument. Some implementations of find require the {} to appear as a standalone argument, and this is a technique to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks. I also got `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`, from `sh` so I just used `bash` instead. I also modified it to keep them in the same subdirectory: `find ./data001 -name "*.png" -exec bash -c 'f={}; fnew=$(rev <<< "$f" | sed 's~/~_~' | rev); echo "mv $f data001/${fnew/.\//}"' \;` (in my case the subdirectory is hard coded - "data001/")

Answer (score 3):

functions to the rescue, updating Jahid's script:

```
function updateFolder
{
    mkdir "$2"
    for folder in "$1"/*; do
    if [[ -d $folder ]]; then
        foldername="${folder##*/}"
        for file in "$1"/"$foldername"/*; do
            filename="${file##*/}"
            newfilename="$foldername"_"$filename"
            cp "$file" "$2"/"$newfilename"
        done
    fi
    done
}
```

used:

```
$ updateFolder /parent /newfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd parent  
for i in \*/*;do mv ${i} newfolder/\`dirname ${i}\`_\`basename ${i}\`;done  
mv newfolder \<whereeveryouwant>
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the existing answers? And especially over the accepted answer that's been validated by the community? Can you offer some explanation about why you chose a different approach and where this might be more appropriate?

Comment: What environment did you write this for? Why are you escaping the first `*` and all the backticks? And why are you using backticks to spawn subshells (using `$(...)` syntax is just about always strongly preferred over backticks to avoid confusion).

Comment: I stumbled upon this solution while solving similar problem and prefer it simply because it seems simpler than other suggestions. Obviously, the key part is second line. The first and third are just for the user's specific request. Backticks are required to evaluate basename and dirname. Written for Oracle Linux Server 8.3, but has nothing special and should work for all linux, I think.